# How to prevent SharePoint 2013 caching static files in layouts folder?

Tags: 2013, caching

When doing development in SP2010, I used to be able to edit files in _layouts/MySolution/... directly in 14 folder and see changes immediately (.js, .css files). That reduced time a lot while developing, and I could copy files back to solution after I am finished.

However, when I modify files in 15 folder in SP2013, SharePoint seems not to pick the changes immediately. It does so after recycling application pool, as well as after some period of time. So I suspect some sort of caching, that was not present in SP2010.

So the question - where is it and how do I turn it off for dev environment?

Note: it is not browser caching. I tried appending .css?QueryStringToForceCacheReload, as well as opening file in browser directly, Ctrl+F5 etc. 
Recycling app pool does help, but the whole point is not to wait for app pool recycling.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this same problem in SharePoint 2016, and was finally able to resolve it by configuring output cache profiles.

Output Cache Profiles are applied at both the site collection level (by clicking the *Site collection output cache* link under Site Collection Administration) and the site level (by clicking *Site output cache* under Site Administration).

However, to prevent caching, it's not sufficient to just apply the "Disabled" cache profile at the site or site collection level. The "Disabled" cache profile itself may need to be adjusted to prevent inadvertent caching.

At the root site of the site collection, in **Site Settings**, you can configure **Site collection cache profiles** (located under Site Collection Administration). The Cache Profiles list contains the selectable options for the output cache on sites within the site collection.

Edit the **Disabled** item in the Cache Profile list. Make sure the **Check for Changes** checkbox is selected, then save the item.

Answer (score 1):

> Configuring object cache settings
>
> The object cache settings can be configured at the site collection
>   level in the user interface by a site collection administrator, and is
>   on by default. The maximum cache size can be configured at the Web
>   application level on the front-end Web server to place a restriction
>   on the maximum amount of memory that the cache will use for all site
>   collections. For example, individual site collections might have the
>   object cache set at 100 MB, while the Web application might be set at
>   1 GB. In this case, no more than 1 GB of memory will be used by all
>   the caches on the server.
>
> 1. Verify that you have the following administrative credentials: You must be a member of the Administrators group on the local computer to
>      configure the object cache settings.
> 2. Click Start, point to Administrative Tools, and then click Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
> 3. In Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager, in the Connections pane, click the plus sign (+) next to the server name that contains
>      the Web application, and then click the plus sign next to Sites to
>      view the Web application or applications that have been created.
> 4. Right-click the name of the Web application for which you want to configure the disk-based cache, and then click Explore. Windows
>      Explorer opens, with the directories for the selected Web application
>      listed.
> 5. Right-click web.config, and then click Open.
> 6. If the Windows dialog box appears, select Select a program from a list of installed programs, and then click OK.
> 7. In the Open With dialog box, click Notepad, and then click OK.
> 8. In the Web.config Notepad file, find the following line: `<ObjectCache maxSize="100" />`
> 9. To change the size of the cache, type a new number for maxSize. The size is expressed in megabytes (MB), and 100 MB is the default.
> 10. Save the Notepad file, and then close it.

Blob caching

> By default, the disk-based BLOB cache is off and must be enabled on
>   the front-end Web server if you want to use it. Use the following
>   procedure to configure disk-based cache settings for a Web
>   application.   Important:
>
> Before you make changes to the web.config file, make a copy of it by
>   using a different name (for example, web.config1), so that if a
>   mistake is made in the file, you can restore the original file.
>
> To configure BLOB cache settings
>
> 1. Verify that you have the following administrative credentials: You must be a member of the Administrators group on the local computer to
>      configure the BLOB cache settings.
> 2. Click Start, point to Administrative Tools, and then click Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
> 3. In Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager, in the Connections pane, click the plus sign (+) next to the server name that contains
>      the Web application, and then click the plus sign next to Sites to
>      view the Web application or applications that have been created.
> 4. Right-click the name of the Web application for which you want to configure the disk-based cache, and then click Explore. Windows
>      Explorer opens, with the directories for the selected Web application
>      listed.
> 5. Right-click web.config, and then click Open.
> 6. If the Windows dialog box appears, select Select a program from a list of installed programs, and then click OK.
> 7. In the Open With dialog box, click Notepad, and then click OK.
> 8. In the web.config Notepad file, find the following line:

```
<BlobCache 
    location="" 
    path="\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|jpe|jfif|bmp|dib|tif|tiff|ico|png|wdp|hdp|css|js|asf|avi|flv|m4v|mov|mp3|mp4|mpeg|mpg|rm|rmvb|wma|wmv)$" 
    maxSize="10" 
    enabled="false" 
/>
```

save and exit, now make your changes and reload the page!

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc770229(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: That doesn't help. Blob caching is not enabled (enabled="false") and object cache - "To use the object cache, you must be using the Publishing feature on your site." - I am _not_ using publishing feature. And anyway, I tried setting maxSize="0" and iisreset, it did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use for example [cks:dev](http://cksdev.codeplex.com/) in visual studio and set the property Auto Copy to SharePoint Root to true of the project. This way you get full control, anyway and I don't have any problems with something getting cached.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be the new [Minimal Download Strategy](http://blogs.technet.com/b/wbaer/archive/2012/11/12/introduction-to-minimal-download-strategy-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx) at play? It's a feature that is enabled by default and helps save bandwidth by not trying to download unnecessary files.

> In SharePoint 2013 Minimal Download Strategy is enabled by default and
>   can be disabled where necessary on a per SPWeb basis using
>   EnableMinimalDownload property and settings its value to False.