# JavsScript/CSS Files in SharePoint Style Library/Site Assets not updating

Tags: development, css, cache, js, blob-cache

We store all code files(.js/.css) in Style Library/Site Assets Library in SharePoint Publishing site. Sometimes, we/end users don’t see the updated JavaScript/CSS files in Browser even after clearing browser cache/restarting computer/adding query string parameter in URL(like /file.js?v=1.0). But, if we download the file manually from SharePoint Library, we could see the changes(updated one). I think it would be related to Blob Cache/Server cache in SharePoint WFE server.

Any insights please?

Kindly let me know if you need any other details. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

yes, this is definitely BLOB Cache, you need to flush BLOB cache.

Below power shell script would do same.

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication "<WebApplicationURL>"
 [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingCache]::FlushBlobCache($webApp)
 Write-Host "Flushed the BLOB cache for:" $webApp
```

Ref [link](https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/how-to-flush-the-blob-cache-in-sharepoint-2013-powershell-script/)

Comment: Since I don't have access to server, wouldn't be able to do it everytime I make changes. I would like to know if anything can be done within site collection level like disabling caching for certain pages/master page/ site settings. Thanks!

Comment: Read about output cache profile here - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/63001/how-to-prevent-sharepoint-2013-caching-static-files-in-layouts-folder

Comment: I have already read that post. Output cache profile is different than Blob cache and Blob cache settings can't be changed/managed by me.

Answer (score 0):

This could also be happened when you forgot to check-in and publish that files. Without publish, only the author can see the changes.

Comment: Its not an issue about check-in/publish. Even some developers who made the actual change don't see it. Thanks!